# Importing Postman Collection into ZAP: "request field is not present"

Tags: postman, owasp, zap

I'm trying to import a Postman collection into OWASP ZAP, in order to do some API pentesting. However, ZAP is giving me a hard time to import the collection. I have removed most of the variables, exported the collection as a json file from Postman, and when importing in ZAP defined the remaining two variables, but it still gives me an error. In the Output window of ZAP it says "Failed to import : request field is not present". And the lastly: "No item could be imported from the collection. Please check if the items exist and if they are valid.".
Any idea what could be missing? Its a perfectly fine working postman collection, so Im at a loss....
Txs!

Comment: The ZAP Postman job is alpha status and so has some restrictions. Can you share a suitably obfuscated collection we can use to reproduce this problem? Ideally via a new ZAP issue: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues

Comment: Thanks Simon; problem is that the API works with an API Key, so I cant share the collection. Or, I could, without client key, but then it surely wont work... But maybe for importing purposes thats OK?

Comment: We dont need access to the target app - I can point it at a local test server :) I'm expecting it to fail while parsing the collection rather than trying to make the actual requests so we should be good.